# Find the length of repeating numbers in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

```
a = 4;
primes = Prime[Range[PrimePi[10^(a - 1)] + 1, PrimePi[10^a]]];
d = 1;
Cases[IntegerDigits[primes], {_, d .., _}]
```

This gets me the list of the numbers from my list of primes that have more than one 1 in a row.

```
{{1, 1, 1, 7}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 3}, {3, 1, 1, 9}, {4, 1, 1, 1},
{5, 1, 1, 3}, {5, 1, 1, 9}, {6, 1, 1, 3}, {8, 1, 1, 1}, {8, 1, 1, 7}}
```

Is there a way to get the length of the repeating digits? For instance, I'd rather get an output of

```
{3,3,2,2,3,2,2,2,3,2}
```

My goal is to get **the count of the ones with the maximum length**.

Comment: Keeping your approach, what about doing: `Cases[IntegerDigits[primes], id : {_, d .., _} :> Count[id, 1]]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I emphasize that the OP wanted the longest sequence of 1s **in a row**.

Consider

```
it = {{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}}
```

Then, [xavier's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129332/find-the-length-of-repeating-numbers-in-a-list#comment349592_129332) gives

```
Cases[it, id : {_, 1 .., _} :> Count[id, 1]]
```

> {}

and [Wouter's answer:](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/129499/22013)

```
Max[Last /@ Tally[#]] & /@ it
```

> {5}

which is incorrect.

---

### This works:

```
Max /@ (Length /@ Select[#, MemberQ[#, 1] &] & /@ Split /@ it)
```

> {3}

and on the exemplary

```
it = {{1, 1, 1, 7}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 3}, {3, 1, 1, 9}, {4, 1, 1, 1},
 {5, 1, 1, 3}, {5, 1, 1, 9}, {6, 1, 1, 3}, {8, 1, 1, 1}, {8, 1, 1, 7}}
```

gives

> {3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2}

---

If `1` is dominant in all sublists (i.e., for sure the longest subsequence of repeating numbers consists of `1`s), like in the case of the last `it`, this will also work:

```
Length /@ Last /@ Sort /@ Split /@ it
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `Longest`

```
dat = {{1, 1, 1, 7}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 3}, {3, 1, 1, 9}, {4, 1, 
    1, 1}, {5, 1, 1, 3}, {5, 1, 1, 9}, {6, 1, 1, 3}, {8, 1, 1, 1}, {8,
     1, 1, 7}};
fun[lst_, d_] := 
 Cases[lst, {___, Longest[x__?(# == d &)], ___} :> Length@{x}]
```

So, `fun[#, 1] &@dat` yields:

```
{3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
it={{1, 1, 1, 7}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 3}, {3, 1, 1, 9}, {4, 1, 1, 1},
 {5, 1, 1, 3}, {5, 1, 1, 9}, {6, 1, 1, 3}, {8, 1, 1, 1}, {8, 1, 1, 7}};
```

now use:

```
Max[Last /@ Tally[#]] & /@ it
```

to get

```
{3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

## MaximalBy + Split + Length + Count

In versions 10.0+, you can use `MaximalBy` in combination with `Split`:

```
list = {{1, 1, 1, 7}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 3}, {3, 1, 1, 9}, {4, 1, 1, 1},
   {5, 1, 1, 3}, {5, 1, 1, 9}, {6, 1, 1, 3}, {8, 1, 1, 1}, {8, 1, 1, 7}};

Composition[Length, First, MaximalBy[Count[#, 1]&], Split] /@ list
```

> {3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2}

```
Composition[Length, First, MaximalBy[Count[#, 1]&], Split]/@ {{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}}
```

> {3}

Answer (score 2):

```
list =
  {{1, 1, 1, 7}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 3}, {3, 1, 1, 9}, {4, 1, 1, 
    1}, {5, 1, 1, 3}, {5, 1, 1, 9}, {6, 1, 1, 3}, {8, 1, 1, 1}, {8, 1, 1, 7}};
```

Using `SequenceCount` (new in 10.1) - short, but slow with long lists

```
SequenceCount[#, {1}] & /@ list
```

{3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2}

```
Max[%]
```

3

Answer (score 2):

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
list = {{1, 1, 1, 7}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 3}, {3, 1, 1, 9}, {4, 1,
    1, 1}, {5, 1, 1, 3}, {5, 1, 1, 9}, {6, 1, 1, 3}, {8, 1, 1, 1}, {8,
    1, 1, 7}};

Max[SequenceCases[#, {p : Repeated[1]} :> Length[{p}]]] & /@ list
(*{3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use [`LongestCommonSubsequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LongestCommonSubsequence):

```
longestRepeat[list_] := Length @ LongestCommonSubsequence[
    ConstantArray[1, Length[list]],
    list
]
```

On the OP example:

```
longestRepeat /@ list
```

> {3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2}

If speed is an issue, here is a simple [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile) approach:

```
fc = Compile[{{l, _Integer, 1}}, 
    Module[{best=0, cur=0},
        Do[
            If[i==1,cur++; best=Max[best,cur], cur=0],
            {i,l}
        ];
        best
    ],
    RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}
];
```

We get the same result as before:

```
fc[list]
```

> {3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2}

Let's compare the suggested answers on a larger example:

```
data = RandomInteger[1, {10^4, 100}];

r1 = longestRepeat /@ data; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = fc[data]; //AbsoluteTiming
r3 = fun[data, 1]; //AbsoluteTiming
r4 = Max/@(Length/@Select[#,MemberQ[#,1]&]&/@Split/@data); //AbsoluteTiming (* corey979 *)
r5 = Composition[Length,First,MaximalBy[Count[#,1]&],Split]/@data; //AbsoluteTiming (* kglr *)

r1 === r2 === r3 === r4 === r5
```

> {0.308581, Null}
>
> {0.011777, Null}
>
> {66.2261, Null}
>
> {0.506145, Null}
>
> {0.943818, Null}
>
> True

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{1, 1, 1, 7}, {2, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 3}, {3, 1, 1, 9}, {4, 1, 1, 1},
        {5, 1, 1, 3}, {5, 1, 1, 9}, {6, 1, 1, 3}, {8, 1, 1, 1}, {8, 1, 1, 7}};
```

Using `Split` and `Cases`:

```
f = Length@First@Cases[{1 ..}]@Split@# &;

f /@ list

(*{3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2}*)

Max[%]

(*3*)
```

Or a slower version using `Sequenceplit`, only for didactic purposes:

```
f[l_] := Length@First@Cases[{1 ..}]@SequenceSplit[l, s : {x_} /; x != 1 :> s]

f /@ list

(*{3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2}*)

Max[%]

(*3*)
```