# Manually modify lists for survival analysis

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics

I have a series of lists of this form: `{1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}`. I would like to perform a survival analysis on these lists. To do that, I need a code that would check each elements of these lists, do nothing as long as these are 1s, but as soon as one element is 0, it would change all the following elements to zero.

As an example, this code would transform the above list to `{1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}`. I can't seem to find a way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take

```
list = {{1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0}}
```

and run

```
list /. {x : 1 ___, z : 0 ___, y___} :> PadRight[{x}, Length@{x, z, y}]
```

> {{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0}}

---

**Original answer:**

```
Cases[list, {x : 1 ___, 0, y___} :> PadRight[{x}, Length @ {x, 0, y}]]
```

> {{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0}}

Equivalents:

```
Cases[list, {x : 1 ___, 0, y___} :> Flatten @ {x, 0, ConstantArray[0, Length @ {y}]}]

Cases[list, {x : 1 ___, 0, y___} :> Join @@ {{x}, {0}, ConstantArray[0, Length @ {y}]}]
```

Fails when a list is composed only of `1`s.

**UPDATE:**

This is a fix:

```
Cases[list, {Longest[x : 0 .. | 1 ..], y___} :> PadRight[{x}, Length @ {x, y}]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works great. So 1___ is the part of the list that is composed of successive 1s?

Comment: `1___` is a pattern saying to take the initial `1`s in the list; the three underscores `___`  indicate to take as many (initial) `1`s there are, including  the case when there are no `1`s in the beginning. Two underscores, `__` would indicate as many `1`s there are but **at least one**, so it would fail to return the proper answer in the case of `list[[3]]`.

Comment: Just as a curio: to get all succesive `1` see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129332/find-the-length-of-repeating-numbers-in-a-list).

Comment: I'm not sure but, I think there might be a problem with the solution that you proposed. I had initially 137 lists, but when I apply your function I only get 103 as output. It is important that I keep the same number of sublists at the end. Would you know how to correct that?

Comment: I found where the problem came from: your code excluded all sublists that were composed exclusively of 1s.

Comment: I edited accordingly; provided a different, working, method.

Comment: Ok, the problem is solved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit**

As [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr) points out in a comment:

```
FoldList[Times]/@list
```

**Original Answer**

```
FoldList[Times, #] & /@ list
```

> {{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
>     0}}

Comment: (+1) You could also use the operator form `FoldList[Times]/@list`.

Comment: @kglr Thanks! Have added your code to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `PositionSmallest` (new in V 13.2)

```
list = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1};

MapAt[0 &, First @ PositionSmallest @ list ;;] @ list
```

{1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}

Or, more generally,

```
list = {2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2};

MapAt[Min @ list &, First @ PositionSmallest @ list ;;] @ list
```

{2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1}

Answer (score 1):

Define a function that changes its definition when it encounters a `0` and map it on the input list:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[list_, v_ : 0, nv_ : 0] := 
 Module[{$f}, $f[x_] := x; $f[v] := $f[_] = nv; Map[$f] @ list]
```

***Examples:***

```
lists = {{1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0}}

f /@ lists
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0}}
> ```

```
f[#, 0, 5] & /@ lists
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {5, 5, 5, 5}, {5   5}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[h]

h[v_ : 0, nv_ : 0] := SequenceReplace[p : {v, ___} :> Splice[nv & /@ p]];
```

***Examples:***

```
lists = {{1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0}};

h[] /@ lists
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0}}
> ```

```
h[0, 5] /@ lists
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {5, 5, 5, 5}, {5, 5}}
> ```

```
WolframLanguageData["SequenceReplace", {"VersionIntroduced",  "DateIntroduced"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Essentially picking an entry from the lower triangularized matrix `t`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
lists = {{1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 
    1}, {0, 0}};

survival[k_List] := 
 Module[{t = 
    SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; i >= j -> 1}, {Length@k, Length@k}]
   , fp0 = First[FirstPosition[k, 0, 0], Length@k + 1]
   },
  If[k[[1]] == 0, ConstantArray[0, Length@k], t[[-1 + fp0]] // Normal]
  ]

survival /@ lists
```

> {{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0,
> 0}}