# How to find the sum for each individual row in a binary matrix until the first zero is reached from left to right.

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, summation, binary

I have a 150 by 300 binary matrix. I would like to sum the 1's for each individual row (from left to right) until the first zero is encountered. For example, if a given row is 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1, the sum should be 6 (the sum should stop at the first zero and not continue to count the other ones). This operation needs to take place for all 150 rows.

For the sake of argument, we can consider a smaller, simpler matrix to work with (5 by 10).

```
binarym = ({
{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
{1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
{1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
{1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}})
```

Row 1's sum should be 3, row 2's 4, row 3's 2...et.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/129693/106)

Answer (score 9):

```
LengthWhile[#, Positive] & /@ binarym
```

> {3, 4, 2, 4, 6}

Or

```
binarym /. {x : Longest[1 ..], __} :> Length[{x}]
```

Comment: Thank you, works beautifully!

Comment: I couldn't believe the efficiency about `LengthWhile`

Comment: You should specify `Length[#]` as a third argument to `FirstPostion`, so it works if there is no 0 in the row.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - even with `Length` it wouldn't work. I deleted it.

Comment: @eldo: Strange. It seems to work with `Flatten[FirstPosition[#, 0, Length[#] + 1] & /@ binarym2 - 1]` in MMA 11.0.1.

Answer (score 8):

**Update:** `ff` works as is in version 9. For versions 10+, as commented by @Mr.Wizard, it needs to be modified to prevent the index `i` from exceeding the length of the input list:

```
ffX[m_] := With[{n = Length@First@m}, Module[{i = 1}, 
  While[i <= n && Positive[#[[i]]], ++i]; i - 1] & /@ m] (* thanks: @Mr.Wizard *)
```

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[f1]
f1 = Module[{i = 1}, While[Positive[#[[i]]], ++i]; i - 1] &;

f1 /@ binarym
```

> {3, 4, 2, 4, 6}

Timings for methods posted so far:

```
ClearAll[fa, fb, fc, fd, fe, ff]
fa[m_] := First /@ SparseArray[1 - m]["MatrixColumns"] - 1
fb[m_] := LengthWhile[#, Positive] & /@ m
fc[m_] := FirstPosition[#, 0] & /@ m - 1 // Flatten
fd[m_] := Length /@ Map[First, Split /@ m, 1]
fe[m_] := Total@FoldList[Times, #] & /@ m
ff[m_] := Module[{i = 1}, While[Positive[#[[i]]], ++i]; i - 1] & /@ m

data = RandomInteger[1, {150, 300}];
{#, First[RepeatedTiming[#@data;]]}&/@ {fa, fb, fc, fd, fe, ff} // Grid[#, Alignment->"."]&
```

[image]

Except `fd` all functions produce the same result

```
Equal@@( # @ data & /@ {fa, fb, fc, fe, ff})
```

> True

and

```
Equal[fa@data, fd@data]
```

> False

For a larger data set:

```
data = RandomInteger[1, {10000, 300}];
{#, First[RepeatedTiming[#@data;]]}&/@ {fa, fb, fc, fd, fe, ff} // Grid[#, Alignment->"."]&
```

[image]

```
Equal@@( # @ data & /@ {fa, fb, fc, fe, ff})
```

> True

Comment: Very nice.  You might want to `Quiet` `Part::partw`.  Also `While[Positive @ #[[++i]]]` is arguably a little cleaner and seems to be as fast.

Comment: `Quiet` was not such a good idea.  The error slows this method by an order of magnitude.  I think you should add explicit testing to prevent `i` exceeding the length of the list.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard. Updated with the change needed for versions 10+.

Comment: (1) I believe `ff2` has an error; you forgot to map it across `m`. (2) I think you should move `Length` outside the loop. (3) Please see my answer below.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard. Not sure i understand (2), could you please edit my post to fix it? Re (3) amazing but expected:)

Comment: @ re (2) I mean doing `n = Length` and then `i <= n`.  Further since we are working with a rectangular array you might as well move that outside the `Map` as well, i.e. `ffX[m_] := With[{n = Length@First@m}, 
  Module[{i = 1}, While[i <= n && Positive[#[[i]]], ++i]; i - 1] & /@ m]`.  Or possibly faster just `ArrayPad` as I did for `ff` in my answer; if `m` is packed it should be fast.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you @Mr.Wizard.

Answer (score 7):

```
First /@ SparseArray[1 - binarym]["MatrixColumns"] - 1
```

> `{3, 4, 2, 4, 6}`

Comment: Pretty! But you have to deal with the case where there are only 1s in one row.

Comment: @JEM_Mosig Pretty reminder.Thanks..

Answer (score 6):

So far the following methods have been proposed:

```
Leading1sByKglr[m_] := Module[{i = 1}, While[Positive[#[[i]]], ++i]; i - 1] & /@ m

Leading1sByEldoA[m_] := LengthWhile[#, Positive] & /@ m

Leading1sByEldoB[m_] := Flatten[FirstPosition[#, 0] & /@ m - 1]

Leading1sByTomd[m_] := Total@FoldList[Times, #] & /@ m

Leading1sByYode[m_] := First /@ SparseArray[1 - m]["MatrixColumns"] - 1

Leading1sByDavidGStork[m_] := Length /@ Map[First, Split /@ m, 1]
```

With the test matrix given in the question they all agree.

```
Equal @@ Through[{
    Leading1sByKglr,
    Leading1sByEldoA,
    Leading1sByEldoB,
    Leading1sByTomd,
    Leading1sByYode,
    Leading1sByDavidGStork
    }[binarym]
  ]
(* True *)
```

However, when given a full list of only 1s or only 0s, `Leading1sByEldoB` and `Leading1sByYode` run into trouble:

```
binarym2 = {ConstantArray[1, 10], ConstantArray[0, 10]};

Leading1sByEldoB[binarym2]
(* {-1 + Missing["NotFound"], 0} *)

Leading1sByYode[binarym2]
(* {-1 + First[{}], 0} *)
```

Performance of the remaining methods:

```
SeedRandom[42];
bigbinarym = RandomInteger[1, {150, 300}];

Through[{
   First@*RepeatedTiming@*Leading1sByKglr,
   First@*RepeatedTiming@*Leading1sByEldoA,
   First@*RepeatedTiming@*Leading1sByTomd,
   First@*RepeatedTiming@*Leading1sByDavidGStork
   }[bigbinarym]
 ] // ScientificForm
(* {8.9*10^(-5), 4.4*10^(-2), 2.1*10^(-3), 9.0*10^(-3)} *)
```

kglr's method seems to be the best.

Answer (score 5):

```
 Total@FoldList[Times, #] & /@ binarym
```

> {3, 4, 2, 4, 6}

Comment: Great use of `Fold`

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, a pattern-based approach that is very readable

```
Replace[binarym, {{0, ___} -> 0, {x : (1 ..), 0, ___} :> Length[{x}]}, 1]
```

Surprisingly, on my machine only kglr's method is faster than this among the ones presented here so far :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Length /@ Map[First, Split /@ binarym, 1]
```

(*

{3, 4, 2, 4, 6}

*)

(This assumes the first element is a $1$ in each row.)

Comment: Thank you! It's nice to see other variations.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to beat kglr's code but I think I succeeded using [`IntegerExponent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerExponent.html).

```
len1[m_] := IntegerExponent[FromDigits[Reverse@#, 2] & /@ BitXor[m, 1], 2]

len1[binarym]
```

> ```
> {3, 4, 2, 4, 6}
> ```

Performance check:

```
m = RandomChoice[{1, 50} -> Range[0, 1], {150, 300}];
m = ArrayPad[m, {0, {0, 1}}];  (* explained below *)

r1 = ff[m];   // RepeatedTiming   (* kglr's function *)
r2 = len1[m]; // RepeatedTiming
r1 === r2
```

> ```
> {0.000914, Null}
>
> {0.000425, Null}
>
> True
> ```

Notes:

- I used [`ArrayPad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPad.html) to make sure that there is always a zero in each row, as your title implies.  If there is not kglr's function as presently written slows down by an order of magnitude due to `Part` errors, and mine returns `∞` for those rows.  `ArrayPad` therefore both keeps the output in agreement and gives kglr's code equal footing.
- I would like to eliminate [`Reverse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reverse.html) by clever application of binary operations.
- My function is optimized to work on a packed array, so please make sure input is packed in any performance tests.

---

Alternate version for additional testing:

```
len2[m_] := IntegerExponent[BitNot[FromDigits[Reverse@#, 2] & /@ m], 2]
```

Comment: It would be interesting comparing the different methods on sparse arrays.

Comment: @Carl If the array in `SparseArray` form to start with I suspect yode's answer or a refinement of it will be fastest as the position information already exists within the data, right?